# What is a “very general abelian variety”?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So my question is same as the title. I am reading a article which mentions “a very general abelian variety”. I am not able to find any clear definition of this term.
I read few answers on math stack exchange on the term “generic” and “general” in algebraic geometry.But the answers seems to work on family of variety and on a property which the family satisfies. But in the article, author is not calling a family to be very general instead a variety over a field to be very general abelian variety.

Kindly help me in understanding the correct definition of the term.
Thanks.

Edit: I am adding article name for the reference : Chow rings and gonality of general abelian variety by Claire Voisin.

Comment: Do you know if that’s a technical term or an informal one? Perhaps you could link to the article for context…

Comment: It’s a technical term.

Comment: Is the ”Convention” on Page 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09195.pdf relevant?

Comment: This is standard terminology in this area, just as Aphelli mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the reference. 
In convention ,author is considering family of abelian varieties. But voisin is considering a  abelian variety over C (see in theorem 1.3) .What would very general mean here?

Comment: Abelian varieties are parameterized by an appropriate moduli space; "very general" means "corresponding to a point of the moduli space lying in the complement of a countable number of proper subvarieties".